# Laravel Get Column Name error

Tags: php, laravel, schema

i'm trying to get all the column name in my database table but i always end up with this error,[image]

**My Controller:**

```
public function gettable()
{
    $points = new Point;
    $columns=$points->getTableColumns('points');


    dd($columns->all());
}
```

**My Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Point extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'name']; 

    public function getTableColumns($table)
    {
        return Schema::getColumnListing($table);
    }

}
```

Can anyone point me to a proper solution thanks..

Comment: Can you show your `Point` Model code?

Comment: Looks like something's wrong with your `Point` model

Comment: Can you show us all of the code in those files?
I want to make sure your model is correct.

Comment: i have updated my model please see

Comment: you don't use regular quotes, this cannot work. use single quote `'` or double quote `"` instead of apostrophe `‘’`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error

you need to use single quote `'` or double quote `"` instead of an apostrophe `‘`
replace this line with 
From

```
protected $guarded = [‘id’, ‘name’];
```

To

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'name'];
```